# How exact do I need to be about replacing disks like-for-like in a RAID 1 NAS? Can I replace a disk with one of greater capacity?

Tags: hard-drive, raid, nas, raid-1

I want to replace one of the disks in my NAS, which currently contains two 6TB disks, arranged in a RAID 1 array. Do I need to replace with a disk of exactly the same size? If "it depends," what does it depend on? Can I freely replace the disk with one of greater size – e.g. 8TB? I intend on keeping the NAS set up as RAID 1.

Specifically I have a [WD My Cloud EX2 Ultra NAS](https://www.westerndigital.com/products/network-attached-storage/wd-my-cloud-expert-series-ex2-ultra?sku=WDBVBZ0000NCH-NESN) which I bought in 2018. It has recently started giving me a warning that one of the disks is bad, so I want to replace it. The disk model is shown as `WDC WD60EFRX-68L0BN1`. I can't find this exact disk model for sale anywhere. I *can* find model number `WD60EFPX` for sale – is this a safe replacement? I don't know how exact HDD manufacturers are about disk space – what if the new drive is (e.g.) 1 MB smaller than the one it's replacing? Will the process fail? What happens then?

Comment: @osullic Just posted my comment as an answer. Feel free to upvote it if it helped you and be sure to check if off as the answer if it is the answer that solved your question.

Answer (score 1):

> “I can't find this exact disk model for sale anywhere. I can find model number WD60EFPX for sale – is this a safe replacement?”

Yes. The first part of a model number is usually the model number and the next part is the revision. The first part is what is important.

That said, you can pretty much use any drive that’s the same capacity and similar specs as a replacement. I know the common wisdom as far as RAID arrays go is: “Exact same make and model.” But the reality is that anything that is the same capacity should work.

If it is higher capacity that would be wasted since the RAID array will rebuild based on the size of other drives. So if you insert an 8TB drive to replace a 6TB drive, only 6TB of that drive will be used; 2TB of that drive will be ignored by the array.

But *do not* insert a drive that is less in capacity to drive it is replacing. That could result in breaking the RAID array.

Comment: @John Thanks! But why do you keep on mentioning RAID 5; the original poster states “RAID 1” is their setup.